# Make Visual Studio XAML output compatible to System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, powershell

I am trying to create a **WPF GUI** in **Visual Studio** (2015) and load the created `XAML` into **Powershell**, via the `[System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::load()` method.

The trouble is, a few basic controls are fine (after some replacements), but as soon as you configure some more properties in VS, you get an endless stream of errors when loading the XAML with the XAMLreader.
***Example***: The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665420/wpf-proportional-resize-of-two-buttons) works fine in VisualStudio, but generates lots of errors when loading it via Xamlreader.

- So, **why** does it not work? The `System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader` is
  [supposed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to follow the same shema as the XAML generated  by VS 
  (at least it states that in its header).
- **How** do I make the VS generated XAML in general compatible to the
  XamlReader?
- And if that is not possible, is there **another way** to load VS
  generated XAML into Powershell?

EDIT: Example:

```
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~ WPF ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$Xaml = @"
<Window  
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Window3"

           Title="Window" Height="40" Width="40" ToolTip="Tooltip" Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" MaxWidth="100" MaxHeight="100" MinWidth="20" MinHeight="20">
    <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label x:Name="Backdrop" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Label" Margin="0,0,0,0" Foreground="{x:Null}" Background="#FFAD3838"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Grid.Column="0" Content="" Margin="1" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FF3B87BD"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button2" Grid.Column="1" Content="" Margin="1" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FF59B483"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
"@
#   Add Type
 Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework,WindowsBase,system.windows.forms

#   read XAML
$inputXML = $Xaml -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N'   
[XML]$script:WpfXml = $inputXML

#   Remove Class, Load Reader
$WpfXml.Window.RemoveAttribute(“x:Class”)
$Reader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $WpfXml
$WpfForm = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($Reader) 
$WpfXml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{  Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $WpfForm.FindName($_.Name) -Scope script  }


$WpfForm.showdialog()
```

Comment: Which errors exactly? I'd expect something like `x:Class` references to throw errors, since PowerShell has no associated class

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say "make it work" and then say "it doesn't matter which specific errors".  We can only fix errors that you tell us about.

Comment: @Moss Remove the `x:Class`, `mc:Ignorable` attributes and close the `Window` tag, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the example you gave is fairly easy to appropriate to a non-VS runtime.

1. Remove the `x:Class` attribute, since we don't have the corresponding class defined
2. Remove the `mc:Ignorable` attribute, since it can't be resolved
3. Add a closing `</Window>` tag, missing from the original example:

---

```
$null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')

$NodeReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $([xml]@'
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExampleWin"
    Title="Window" Height="200" Width="200" ToolTip="Tooltip" Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
<Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="Backdrop" Content="Label" Margin="0,0,0,0" Foreground="{x:Null}" Background="#FFAD3838"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="" Margin="1,1,99,1" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FF3B87BD"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button2" Content="" Margin="99,1,1,1" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FF59B483"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
</Window>
'@)

$Window = [System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($NodeReader)
$Window.ShowDialog()
```

[image]

---

For completeness, the example from the *answer* to the question you linked to:

```
$null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')

$NodeReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $([xml]@'
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExampleWin"
    Title="Window" Height="200" Width="200" ToolTip="Tooltip" Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
<Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" UseLayoutRounding="True">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label x:Name="Backdrop" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Label" Margin="0,0,0,0" Foreground="{x:Null}" Background="#FFAD3838"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Grid.Column="0" Content="" Margin="1" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FF3B87BD"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button2" Grid.Column="1" Content="" Margin="1" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FF59B483"/>
</Grid>
</Border>
</Window>
'@)

$Window = [System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($NodeReader)
$Window.ShowDialog()
```

[image]

Comment: You did not take the code from the **ANSWER**. As I said it gets more problematic with increased complexity of the xaml.

Comment: Because of `-replace 'x:N','N'` - you're breaking the namespace reference for the Name attributes and the `{x:Null}` value reference

Comment: Thats it. Seems my impression of the many errors were just due to the unhelpful error messages which were pointing in the wrong direction. thanks again and sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @Moss No worries, happy to help :-)